# IllegalStateException calling MediaPlayer.seek() from onPrepared()

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have an app that calls `MediaPlayer.onPrepared()` from the `onPreparedListener.onPrepared()` callback.  In tests it works fine, but periodically, I get a crash report indicating that it threw an `IllegalStateException`.  The [MediaPlayer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(int)) state that the exception should be thrown "if the internal player engine has not been initialized".  However, it seems that receiving the callback indicates that the initialization is complete.  I never invoke the callback manually.  Any thoughts?

Comment: There must a problem in sequence of states. Android media player works as per states. if Media Player is not moved from correct state. Then it throws IlligalStateException. Once go through state sequence of MediaPlayer. Flow chart is available for that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  However, the `onPreparedListener` is called on the transition to the `prepared` state, where `seek` is a valid operation.

Comment: Your welcome frnd :), kindly accept in answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: If you are in onPreapred() method, I think you need to call .start() before seek().

Comment: `start()` moves the state to the `started` state, where `seek` is also valid.  The docs indicate that `seek` is also valid in the prepared state.  Maybe some implementations don't support that, however.

Comment: The crashes are spread across a wide range of devices, nearly all of which are Samsung Galaxy devices.  It may have something to do with Samsung's media framework.

Answer (score 0):

There must a problem in sequence of states. Android media player works as per states. if Media Player is not moved from correct state. Then it throws IlligalStateException. Once go through state sequence of MediaPlayer.

Comment: As I mentioned above, and as the chart from the mediaplayer docs that you included shows, `onPrepared` is called on the transition to the `Prepared` state.  In the `Prepared` state, `seekTo` is a valid call.  I'm afraid that pasting the chart does not address my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is still untested, but I believe I have a solution.  I was calling `prepare()` on a background thread, rather than `prepareAsync()` on the UI thread.  I think this resulted in `onPrepared()` being called at strange times.  I will comment here to verify that this solved the problem.